# How to use python to create a pointer for linked list

Tags: python, pointers, linked-list

I'm creating a linked list in python and am trying to concatenate all nodes. Initially my code looks like this:

```
class Node: 
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val=val
        self.next=None

a=[1,2,3,4,5]

new_l=Node(a[0])
ptl=new_l.next
for i in range(1, 5):
    ptl=Node(a[i])
    ptl=ptl.next
# return new_l
```

My initial intention of `ptl=Node(a[i])` is to link `Node(a[i])` to current location `ptl`. However, the actual effect is, python create a new `Node(a[i])` (in a new random location) and let `ptl` points to `Node(a[i])` instead. Therefore, I lost track of the previous position where the list was.

I figured out a way to bypass the issue by modifying the code as:

```
b=[1,2,3,4,5]

new_l=Node(b[0])
ptl=new_l
for i in range(1, 5):
    ptl.next=Node(b[i])
    ptl=ptl.next
```

and it works. However, I'm still wondering if there's a way to write `name=value`(like in C++) to change the value at the location "name", rather than creating a value (and some other location) and call it "name" instead.

It seems python "variables" behave like something between C++ variables and C++ pointers.

Comment: I don't know why do you want to creat a linked list based on `list`, in which case you cannot really *delete* a node in O(1) time unless you want to leave the deleted element in the memory during the list's lifetime and make your code seems very strange.

Comment: Variable assignment is fundamentally an entirely different operation in Python than it is in C or C++. Trying to make `=` work the same way in Python as it does in C++ is like a French speaker trying to make the English word "pain" mean "bread".

Comment: See https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: @JohnDing Frankly speaking, it's leetcode that asks me do such things. (Or I can say, just for learning purpose)

Comment: @GuixinLiu Although I advocate that beginners can write some not practical code for gradual understanding, using `list` to represent a *linked list* in completely nonsense in python to my mind.